# Hot to port entrySet() method from HashMap<Integer,Object> to trove4j?

Tags: java, hashmap, trove4j

I was often iterating over hashmaps by `entrySet()` method, expecting this is faster. Now I would like to port some of my code to trove's [`TIntObjectHashMap`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/TIntObjectMap.html), but don't see the method to enumerate entries.

Why? How to port?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the most speed, you should look at the [forEach*](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/TIntObjectMap.html#forEachEntry%28gnu.trove.procedure.TIntObjectProcedure%29) methods. They are the most efficient method to iterate. Otherwise, there are [iterator methods](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/TIntObjectMap.html#iterator%28%29) as well as methods for directly getting the [keys in array form](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/TIntObjectMap.html#iterator%28%29) which may be the easiest to port to. However, if speed is your primary concern I would recommend the forEach* methods.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the [http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/TIntObjectMap.html#iterator()](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/TIntObjectMap.html#iterator%28%29) method (the iterator provides access to the current key).